# Binding List<CompositeControl> to a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a collection of generated custom controls that extend `CompositeControl`, defined as:

```cs
[PersistChildren(true)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ContractControl runat=server></{0}:ContractControl>")]
public class ContractControl : CompositeControl
{
    private int contractID = 0;
    private ContractTileControl tileControl = null;
    private ContractDetailControl detailControl = null;

    private HtmlGenericControl contractMainDiv = null;

    public int ContractID
    {
        get { return this.contractID; }
        set { this.contractID = value; }
    }

    public ContractTileControl TileControl
    {
        get { return this.tileControl; }
        set { this.tileControl = value; }
    }

    public ContractDetailControl DetailControl
    {
        get { return this.detailControl; }
        set { this.detailControl = value; }
    }

    public ContractControl()
    {
        this.contractMainDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        this.contractMainDiv.ID = "contractMainDiv";
        this.contractMainDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "contractMain");
    }

    #region protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        //CreateChildControls();
    }
    #endregion

    #region protected override void CreateChildControls()
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        if (tileControl != null)
        {
            this.contractMainDiv.Controls.Add(tileControl);
        }

        if (detailControl != null)
        {
            this.contractMainDiv.Controls.Add(detailControl);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(contractMainDiv);
        //base.CreateChildControls();
    }


    #endregion

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        EnsureChildControls();
    }
}
```

Where `ContractTileControl` and `ContractDetailControl` are another custom controls derived from `CompositeControl`.

When I add them to a `asp:PlaceHolder` control set they render fine, but when I define a repeater like:

```cs
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td><easit:ContractControl ID="contractControl" runat="server" />
        </td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And bind them to it:

```cs
private void FillContractPlaceHolder()
    {

        List<ContractControl> controls = new List<ContractControl>();
        foreach(KeyValuePair<Customer, List<TFSContract>> pair in contractList)
        {
            Label customerNameLbl = new Label();
            customerNameLbl.ID = "customerNameLbl";
            customerNameLbl.CssClass = "customerName";
            customerNameLbl.Text = pair.Key.Name;
            contractListPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(customerNameLbl);

            foreach (TFSContract contract in pair.Value)
            {
                ContractStatusBarControl status = new ContractStatusBarControl();
                status.WidthPercent = GetFillPercent(contract.NumberOfTasks, contract.NumberOfFinishedTasks);

                string[] contractNameParts = Regex.Split(contract.Contract.Name, @"[A-Z]{3}-[0-9|A-Z]{2}-[0-9|A-Z]{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                ContractDetailControl detail = new ContractDetailControl();
                detail.ContractName = contractNameParts.Last();
                detail.DateStarted = contract.StartDate;
                detail.DateFinished = contract.FinishDate;
                detail.StatusBar = status;

                ContractTileControl tile = new ContractTileControl();
                Match match = Regex.Match(contract.Contract.Name, @"[A-Z]{3}-[0-9|A-Z]{2}-[0-9|A-Z]{2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (match.Value.Length != 0)
                {
                    tile.ContractNumber = match.Value;
                }

                tile.ContractTasksFinished = contract.NumberOfFinishedTasks;
                tile.ContractTasksTotal = contract.NumberOfTasks;

                ContractControl contractControl = new ContractControl();
                contractControl.ContractID = contract.Contract.Id;
                contractControl.TileControl = tile;
                contractControl.DetailControl = detail;
                //contractListPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(contractControl);
                controls.Add(contractControl);
            }


        }

        myRepeater.DataSource = controls;
        myRepeater.DataBind();

    }
```

The table gets created, but only the non-composite part `contractMainDiv` of `ContractControl` gets rendered, as the Repeater insists that both `tileControl` and `detailControl` are null, even though they are properly set to instances of their respective types.

Comment: what are you doing in  base.CreateChildControls();? where you create tileControl and detailControl ?

Comment: Well whatever the base method is doing. tileControl and detailControl are created on Page_Load in the same page that has the repeater, then set through the property that exposes them.
It works quite nicely when using just a placeholder and adding them to its controls collection, but I suspect I am not binding it correctly to the repeater.

Comment: I think error should be there, are you sure you assign this property for all instances of repeater in page load? in case of placeholder you have one instance of ContractControl, in case of repeater more than one, could you show the initialization code?

Comment: Edited, it shows how it's initialized now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Repeater` is data-bound, it creates an instance of the `ItemTemplate` for each item in the data-source, set its `DataItem` to the item from the data-source, and data-binds the children.

In this case, the item from the data-source is an instance of your `ContractControl`, and your `ItemTemplate` has no data-binding, so you'll end up with a blank instance of the `ContractControl` for each item you've added to the list.

The quick and dirty solution is to add a handler for the `ItemDataBound` event of your `Repeater`, and copy the properties to the real control:

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.Item.ItemType)
   {
      case ListItemType.Item:
      case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
      case ListItemType.SelectedItem:
      case ListItemType.EditItem:
      {
         var source = (ContractControl)e.Item.DataItem;
         var destination = (ContractControl)e.Item.FindControl("contractControl");
         destination.ContractID = source.ContractID;
         destination.TileControl = source.TileControl;
         destination.DetailControl = source.DetailControl;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

A better solution would be to bind your `Repeater` to a list of `TFSContract` objects, and moving the code to build the `ContractControl` into the `ItemDataBound` event handler.

**EDIT**
Updated to only process real items, ignoring headers, footers, etc.

Comment: First - thanks for the answer, but I have a bit of a problem. In your example destination is always null, probably because of auto-generating IDs.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, I had assumed the `easit:ContractControl` is a `ContractControl` with `ID="contractControl"` set. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm sorry, it happened because I forgot to filter out header/footer templates. Anyway thanks very much for your answer, I've moved the generating code to `myRepeater_ItemDataBound` event and it works like a charm. :)